# Razorpay Payment id returns null in onPaymentError Android

Tags: java, android, razorpay

I want to get the payment/transaction id from Razorpay when payment fails

```
@Override
public void onPaymentError(int i, String s, PaymentData paymentData) {
try {
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(paymentData.getPaymentId()); //This Value is returns null
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.getMessage();
}
}
```

I get the payment ID during payment success but during payment failure, the payment ID seems to be null. How to get the payment/transaction ID when the payment fails?

Comment: Which razorpay sdk version you are using?. [Latest documentation](https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/android-integration/standard/#step-5---handle-success-and-error-events) does not have `PaymentData` argument on `onPaymentError` listener. Check error response string `s` if it has payment id.

Comment: I am using the latest Razorpay sdk. String `s` returns **payment canceled**

Answer (score 0):

I think you won't getId since your payment has failed it means that no transaction has occured. So `no transaction == no id`.

Comment: Let's take this scenario. I'm doing a bank transaction and it fails. The money doesn't get transacted but it'll create an ID. Similarly, is there any transaction ID I could capture in Razorpay?

Comment: Then if transaction has happened then you will get id.
You can check in razorpay's dashboard

Comment: I checked the dashboard and there is a transaction ID even if the payment fails. I cannot get the failed transaction ID in android.

Comment: Which dependency version are you using??

Comment: 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.4.9' and 'com.razorpay:razorpay-java:1.3.8'

Comment: Ok but in latest version there isn't any payment data onPaymentError if payment is failed then it will ask for payment again

Comment: So will we never get the payment ID until the payment gets through?

Comment: I guess according to new API if payment is failed then it asks for payment again
And if user exits from sdk then onPaymentError is called

Comment: In my case error response String s itself is coming empty for few users in production. In which case response will be empty. I'm using Razorpay sdk 1.6.18